# How do I process a response from a remote REST API (Paypal)?

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to figure out the [Paypal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment).

I have an action for the ReturnURL (`/payment/return`) and an action for the CancelUrl (`/payment/cancel`).

When I generate the Payment: `Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(this.accessToken);`

I get the `approved_url` which I need to redirect for my user so he/she can make the actual Paypal Payment. When the user is done, Paypal sends back an approved Payment object (JSON).

I am trying to get my hands on that JSON in the return action so it will bind to the Payment object.

This does not work:

```
public ActionResult Return(Payment payment)
{
    payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];
    var paymentId = payment.id; // NullException
    var result = paypalService.ExecutePayment(paymentId, payerId);
    return this.View();
}
```

How do I bind the response JSON?

Comment: do you know what returned json looks like

Comment: Lets say I did not want to model bind it, but just access the JSON directly. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to read json there are many ways to do this but if you do not want to bind you can use dynamic

```
   dynamic reply= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring)
```

also take a look at this

http://www.masnun.com/2011/07/08/quick-json-parsing-with-c-sharp.html